# Método mais simples para alterar parâmetros GET

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Não entendo muito de programação e preciso inserir no meu site uma função simples.

O caso é o seguinte:

Um usuário clica em um link como:

```
http://site.com.br/titulo-da-noticia?id=1
```

Eu preciso remover a parte `?ida=1` da URL e adicionar, por exemplo, `?parametro=1&a=2`, carregando a url:

```
http://site.com.br/titulo-da-noticia?parametro=1&a=2
```

Alguém pode gerar este código ou mostrar qual o caminho mais rápido?
Muito obrigado!
Abs.

Comment: Posta o seu código. Isso é bem simples, mas sem o código não adianta.

Comment: É um site em wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Já que o site é feito no WP, vai em no painel (wp-admin) e Configurações > Links Permanentes.

Você pode escolher entre as configurações comuns ou personalizar de acordo com suas preferências.